# UITapGestureRecognizer with collapsible sidebar menu Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am currently programming an app which contains a home screen view controller and a sidebar menu view which is instantiated upon loading the home screen and is opened when clicking a hamburger icon. I am trying to implement the feature that clicking outside of the menu while it's open closes the menu, and restores normal function to the home view, which was disabled upon opening the menu. 
I've instantiated a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `viewDidLoad()` to detect when the user taps on the home view.

```
    let tapRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.handleTap(_:)))
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

And here's the implementation:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if menu.isMenuOpen {
        menu.showMenu(false)
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
    }
}
```

However, tapping on the menu closes the menu just the same as tapping outside of the menu. Also, because the tap gesture recognizer only recognizes that specific tap, everything on the home screen is always disabled. I am running XCode 7.3 on iOS 9.3. Image:
[Home view controller with menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN99T.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and set `tapRecognizer.delegate = self`.

Then implement below method

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer == tapRecognizer){
    let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        if CGRectContainsPoint(menuView.frame, point) == true {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured that out in the last ten minutes, using a similar solution! Thanks for the help though!